# Как автоматически расставлять порядок свойств в .css файле в vs code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, плагин

Добрый день есть вот такой пример:

```
.container1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;          
 }
```

Согласно кодстайла порядок свойств должен быть следующий:

```
.container1 {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   font-family: Arial;
   background-color: red;
```

}
Можно ли что бы в vs code расстановка свойств в правильном порядке делалось автоматически?

Comment: правильный порядок, это такой порядок, который обратный алфавитному?

Comment: @DiD Правильный порядок - это порядок, когда сперва идут свойства позиционирования, затем блочной модели, потом - шрифты. В самом конце - прочее оформление и анимации. (https://codeguide.maxgraph.ru)